# Android Global Menu Architecture Suggestions

Tags: android, android-layout

We have implemented a facebook-like style menu to our app, which basically allows you to click a button and to slide the view over the side to access a menu hidden behind the top level view.

Currently, we have all of our views (this app has lots of screens) in separate XML files as any typical Android app. I should note we make heavy use of fragments.

The goal is to abstract the code out in such a way that instead of inflating our activities and fragments to the top level view, instead now we'd inflate it into this child of this top-level parent that would be a part of all of our activities (all of our activities subclass from a custom activity).

The way the menu.xml works is by having an outer FrameLayout that hosts a nested child FrameLayout that's empty.

*What we are trying to avoid doing is wrapping this outer menu code around every single one of our views XMLs, although this would certainly work.*

I'm trying to find a programmatic way of having the menu code with the empty, nested FrameLayout in one file. Then when we go to inflate a Fragment's or Activity's XML, like so:

```
listView = (PullToRefreshListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pull_to_refresh_list_view, container, false);
```

instead of doing that, we'd inflate it into the nested child FrameLayout. Something like this is what I'm attempting:

```
listView = (PullToRefreshListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pull_to_refresh_list_view, container, false);
    ((FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.child)).addView(listView);
```

Currently this results in: "Unable to resume activity. No view found for id 0x7f090019 for fragment MyFragment[id= 0x7f090019]"

Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for a similar style menu was to add a frame layout and inflate a fragment into it. I then used a translateAnimation and layoutApp to translate the screen to the right place. I kept all this code in a slidingDrawerActivity which segmented the code nicely so that I could just call SlideOutMenu to use it

Hope this helps - if you want more deets just let me know

EDIT:

code for replacing frame layout with a fragment using support library

```
FragmentTransaction FT=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FT.replace(R.id.yourFrameLayout, new YourFragment(), yourFragmentTag);
FT.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
FT.commit();
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the 'inflating a fragment into it' part. It's possible this issue is related to my custom parent activity, not sure yet.

Comment: Are you using the compatibility library? if so you need to use extend a FragmentActivity instead of a normal activity and use the get support fragment manager. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: The parent activity is a FragmentActivity.